# Timeout exception when running SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, list, populate

Trying to populate a `List` with the following code:

```
string sql = ";WITH getUniqueParams AS (" +
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [a] AS 'param' FROM table " +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [b] AS 'param' FROM table " + 
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [c] AS 'param' FROM table " +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [d] AS 'param' FROM table " + 
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [e] AS 'param' FROM table " +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [f] AS 'param' FROM table " +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [g] AS 'param' FROM table " + 
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [h] AS 'param' FROM table " +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [i] AS 'param' FROM table " +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [j] AS 'param' FROM table " +
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [k] AS 'param' FROM table) " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [param] FROM getUniqueParams ORDER BY [param]";   //the result of this statement to be stored in a string

            List<string> lUniqueParams = new List<string>();

            // set up SQL connection and command
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlGetUniqueParams, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                // get a SqlDataReader to read multiple rows
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) //getting exception here when debugging
                {
                    // while there are more result rows.....
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        // grab the 0-index value from the result row
                        lUniqueParams.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
```

Im getting the exception at the following line of code:

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

Is my query not syntactically correct? The query does not perform well, does the rdr only read so long with no results and then give an exception?  Am I missing something?

Comment: How many rows are there in the table? Try to remove `distinct` keywords, use `union` instead of `union all` and remove ordering.

Comment: There are 260 rows in the table

Comment: Then your table may be locked. Try to use `nolock` and see. 260 rows is nothing...

Comment: whats the exception? what happens when you run the query directly in management studio?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, `Timeout exception when running SQL query in C#`

Comment: That's what I'm saying....doubt the table is locked....dev db and Im the only one using the db.

Comment: Does the query take more than 30 seconds in query studio?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it takes 2 min in SQL Server

Comment: 260 are distinct rows or what? What does this give `select count(*) from table`?

Comment: @JeffOrris Then check by increasing timeout in your connection string or try to optimize query so the time comes down.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri The distinct rows is what the CTE generates which = 260

Comment: I've manipulated the connection string timeout in SSIS configurations before but not in actual connection string.  What do I add to the connection string to increase this?

Comment: @JeffOrris, again... what does this give `select count(*) from table`?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri count(*) from table gives 1,000,000~  btw.  I tried using `UNION` but slowed it down....however, changed back to union and only grabbed the distinct at end of CTE and sped up by about 2 min

Comment: Add `cmd.CommandTimeout= 0;` and check.

Comment: @Ullas haha yes! that did the trick.  will optimize that query tomorrow; just needed that working at least a few times  tonight to test something.

Comment: @Jeff change table to [table] in your query and also change using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlGetUniqueParams, conn)) to using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me please check this: as change table to [table] in your query and also change using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlGetUniqueParams, conn)) to using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))

```
string sql = ";WITH getUniqueParams AS (" +
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [a] AS 'param' FROM [table]" +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [b] AS 'param' FROM [table]" + 
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [c] AS 'param' FROM [table]" +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [d] AS 'param' FROM [table]" + 
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [e] AS 'param' FROM [table]" +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [f] AS 'param' FROM [table]" +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [g] AS 'param' FROM [table]" + 
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [h] AS 'param' FROM [table]" +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [i] AS 'param' FROM [table]" +  
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [j] AS 'param' FROM [table]" +
                               "UNION ALL " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [k] AS 'param' FROM [table]) " + 
                               "SELECT DISTINCT [param] FROM getUniqueParams ORDER BY [param]";   //the result of this statement to be stored in a string

            List<string> lUniqueParams = new List<string>();

            // set up SQL connection and command
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                // get a SqlDataReader to read multiple rows
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) //getting exception here when debugging
                {
                    // while there are more result rows.....
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        // grab the 0-index value from the result row
                        lUniqueParams.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I fixed it yesterday per @ullas comment to my question: "Add cmd.CommandTimeout= 0; and check"; changing `table` to `[table]` wouldn't of mattered; `table` was just a dummy name for SO purposes ;) +1 because that could've been an issue, but you didn't know